# How to declare input/output ports dynamically (show/no show) in verilog?

Tags: verilog

What I mean is beside the of using parameters and port array(or flatten array method), is it possible to dynamically enable/disable the input/output port?
more specifically, given an simply module as below, is it possible to only show
B_IN, B_OUT only when required (B_EN=1)?

example

```
module  WEIRD_MOD#(
parameter integer WIDTH_A=8,
parameter integer B_EN=0,
parameter integer WIDTH_B=13;
)
(   
    input   [WIDTH_A-1:0]  A_IN,
    output  [WIDTH_A-1:0]  A_OUT,

// ******************************//
// only valid/show when  B_EN =1 //
// ******************************//
//input     [WIDTH_B-1:0]  B_IN,
//output    [WIDTH_B-1:0]  B_OUT,

);

genvar idx_bit;
generate
    for( idx_bit=0; idx_bit<WIDTH_A; idx_bit= idx_bit+1) 
    begin
        bit_inv inv_inst(.IN(A_OUT[idx_bit]),.OUT(A_OUT[idx_bit]));       
    end

if(B_EN) 
begin
      for( idx_bit=0; idx_bit<WIDTH_B; idx_bit= idx_bit+1) 
      begin
        bit_buf buf_inst(.IN(B_OUT[idx_bit]),.OUT(B_OUT[idx_bit]));
      end
end

endgenerate

endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

No, Verilog does not allow you to change the number of ports or their directions using parameters. Using macros like `` `ifdef `` and `` `define `` can only change them for all instances.

One thing you could do is combine the width of A and B ports into a single port when B_EN is enabled.

```
module  WEIRD_MOD#(
parameter integer WIDTH_A=8,
parameter integer B_EN=0,
parameter integer WIDTH_B=13;
)
(   
    input   [WIDTH_A-1 + (B_EN ? WIDTH_B : 0) :0]  AB_IN,
    output  [WIDTH_A-1 + (B_EN ? WIDTH_B : 0) :0]  AB_OUT,
);

genvar idx_bit;
generate
    for( idx_bit=0; idx_bit<WIDTH_A; idx_bit= idx_bit+1) 
    begin
        bit_inv inv_inst(.IN(A_OUT[idx_bit]),.OUT(A_OUT[idx_bit]));       
    end

if(B_EN) 
begin
      for( idx_bit=0; idx_bit<WIDTH_B; idx_bit= idx_bit+1) 
      begin
        bit_buf buf_inst(.IN(B_OUT[idx_bit+WIDTH_A]),.OUT(B_OUT[idx_bit+WIDTH_A]));
      end
end

endgenerate

endmodule
```

Comment: Hey Dave, do you know if SV supports this feature? Declaring ports based on parameter value....

Answer (score -1):

You can use preprocessor directives like `` `ifdef ``, `` `ifndef `` for controlling the compilation during run time.

http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/compiler1.html

for any further references you can go through this site.

Comment: `ifdef, `ifndef

Comment: I am not able to type it correctly, its tick ifdef and tick ifndef

Answer (score -2):

No you can't do that. Please note that Verilog is an HDL and hence it is to develop a hardware, not a software. And as in hardware you can't have variable number of pins, similarly in Verilog also you can't have variable ports.

Even if you use `define` or `ifdef` macros, still they are preprocessor directives 
and after synthesis, you will have only one hardware with fixed ports.

> You can always ignore the unnecessary ports, but can't have variable
>   ports.

Comment: Parameterizable hardware is a useful thing, unlike this answer.